# Why is react not posting res.json() to console?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, fetch-api

I have tried so many thing but my react app is not recieving jsonData variable or res as a return from the node app. The app is working and printing to console on the node side but I can't get it to print onto the react side.

```
  const submitForm = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default submission
    const data2 = document.getElementById("miles").value;
    const data =
      "passenger_vehicle-vehicle_type_" +
      carType +
      "-fuel_source_" +
      vehicleType +
      "-engine_size_na-vehicle_age_na-vehicle_weight_na";
    axios
      .post(`http://localhost:8000/api/vehicle/`, { data, data2 })
      .then((res) => {
        const returnText = res.json();
        console.log(returnText);
        return res.json();
      })
      .then((jsonData) => {
        console.log(jsonData);
        return;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("got errr while posting data", error);
      });
  };
```

I edited out the api and api key.

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

exports.vehicle = (req, res) =>{
let status; 
const { data, data2 } = res.body;
const values = {
  "emission_factor": data,
  "parameters": {
    "distance": parseInt(data2),
    "distance_unit": "mi",
  },
};

fetch('https://AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer MYAPIKEY',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(values)
})
  .then((res) => { 
    status = res.status;
    return res.json()
  })
  .then((jsonData) => {
    console.log(jsonData);
    console.log(status);
    return jsonData
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // handle error
    console.error(err);
  });
res.send(req.body);
}
```

Working code thanks for the help:

```
const submitForm = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent default submission
    const data2 = document.getElementById("miles").value;
    const data =
      "passenger_vehicle-vehicle_type_" +
      carType +
      "-fuel_source_" +
      vehicleType +
      "-engine_size_na-vehicle_age_na-vehicle_weight_na";
    axios
      .post(`http://localhost:8000/api/vehicle/`, { data, data2 })
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.data);
        return;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("got err while posting data", error);
      });
  };
```

Node solution in comments.

Comment: You have a couple of excellent replies.  Please "upvote" and "accept" if you find them helpful.  ALSO: where exactly are you *looking* for `console.log()` and `console.error()` messages.  I *HOPE* you're looking in the [Console] tab in Chrome Dev Tools (or equivalent).  I hope you don't think they're displayed in a command prompt window :(

Answer (score -1):

The functions inside your then() statements need to return data e.g. `then((res) => {return res.json()})`

Answer (score -1):

You have two problems here...

1. Client-side, you seem to be mixing up an [Axios response](https://github.com/axios/axios#response-schema) with a `fetch()` [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response). You want `res.data`, **not** `res.json()`. Since you've tagged this with [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs), here is where you would set the data to a state value, eg

   ```js
   axios.post(...).then(res => {
     setSomeState(res.data)
   })
   ```
2. Server-side, you aren't waiting for your fetch request to complete. I'd recommend using an `async` function

   ```js
   exports.vehicle = async (req, res) => {
     try {
       const { data, data2 } = req.body

       const values = {
         "emission_factor": data,
         "parameters": {
           "distance": parseInt(data2),
           "distance_unit": "mi",
         },
       }

       // don't mix up the Express "res" with the fetch "response"
       const response = await fetch('https://AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA', {
         method: 'POST',
         headers: {
           'Authorization': 'Bearer MYAPIKEY',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
         },
         body: JSON.stringify(values)
       })

       if (!response.ok) {
         throw new Error(`${response.status}: ${await response.text()}`)
       }

       res.json(await response.json()) // respond with the data
     } catch (err) {
       console.error(err)
       res.status(500).send(err)
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: If there's a problem with this answer, I'd love to know what it is so I can fix it

Comment: I think it's req.body but that's it. It's all working now, thanks for your help.

Comment: @joe cheers, copy / paste error